# Duplicate Parameter in URL React Js / Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I am trying to build a Multi language React website, I have been struggling until i finally I prepare the structure, and now I am facing a problem which I think due to my misunderstanding of React Routes.

I have a MainLayout Layout which provide Header / Main and Footer which contain links.
Using Image would be easy to describe.

1. Home Page Navigation

[image: HomePage]

2. Category Page Navigation

[image: CategoryPage]

3. When i click again on Power on Category Page

[image: CategoryPage]

**http://localhost:3000/en/category/power/category/power**

**App.js**

```
const base = '/:lang([de|en|fr]{2})';
const fallback = '/en';
export const App = ({ store, history }) => {
return(
    <Suspense fallback={<p>...Loading</p>}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path={base} component={BaseRoutes} />
                            <Redirect to={fallback} />
                        </Switch>
                    </ConnectedRouter>
                </ApolloProvider>
            </Provider>
        </I18nextProvider>
    </Suspense>
)}
```

**Routes.js**

```
const BaseRoutes = ({match}) => {
return (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${match.url}/`} component={Home} />
        <Route exact path={`${match.url}/:page`} component={Dynamic}/>
        <Route exact path={`${match.url}/category/:category`} component={Category}/>
        <Route exact path={`${match.url}/detail/:url`} component={DetailArticle}/>
    </Switch>
   );
  };
export default withRouter(BaseRoutes);
```

**Main Layout**

```
const MainLayout = (props) => {
return (
    <>
        <Header/>
        <main>
            {props.children}
        </main>
        <Footer/>
    </>
 );
};
```

**Navigation Link In header**

```
<Nav>
      <Nav.Link to={`${match.url}`} as={Link} >{t('home')}</Nav.Link>
      {data.allCategories.map(item => (
       <Nav.Link to={`${match.url}/category/${item.url}`} as={Link}>
            {item.name}
       </Nav.Link>
        ))}
</Nav>
```

Should I test in every component the match URL ? Or there is any other way to do that ?
I am using the latest Version of React / React Router

Thanks for any Tips or Help!

Livd Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nav-bug-5o2fyx

Comment: The nested routes should probably be using `match.path` instead of `match.url`. Outside this, the code has a lot of pieces and we've not quite a complete enough a context to reproduce this. Think you could provide a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this navigation/routing issue that we could inspect and debug live? We likely don't need anything higher than the `ConnectedRouter`, you could probably just sub in the `Router` from `react-router-dom` and pass the created `history` object to it.

Comment: thanks for your answer I will provide a codesandbox for that

Comment: Shoot, sorry, I meant to also link the [RRDv5 nesting demo](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting).

Comment: @DrewReese here i made a Codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nav-bug-5o2fyx

I really don't know if I should nest the routes like that! 
I updated my question

Comment: To see the behavior, you need to refresh the page when you go to category (link)

Comment: KOseare's answer below is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you make the "to" param of the Nav.Link:

```
<Nav.Link to={`${match.url}/category/${item.url}`} as={Link}>
  {item.name}
</Nav.Link>
```

The match.url is your current url, then you are concatenating it with the /category/${item.url}, so it's likely to have a repetition because you always use the  previous url.

A possible solution could be use the lang parameter that you have assigned:

```
<Nav.Link
  to={`/${match.params.lang}/category/${item.url}`}
  as={Link}
>
  {item.name}
</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work, you saved my day! I've tried to use the Lang parameter, but I didn't consider the "/" before the match for the absolute path!